# bigQuery ANY_VALUE non-deterministic?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is bigQuery ANY_VALUE deterministic? I have a query that produces ~200,000 rows of results but if I filter out duplicate entries after the query, they reduce down to about ~500. To solve that problem in the query itself, I added a GROUP BY and then wrapped all the attributes with `ANY_VALUE(tN.fieldX) as tN_fieldX . The output, when sorted, saved as .csv and executed several times, returns the same md5sum file of results.

Does this mean that the ANY_VALUE is solving my problem of duplicate entries because it would give different values every time due to being non-deterministic in bigQuery?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, ANY_VALUE is non-deterministic - but if you apply the function against the GROUP'ed BY value - it kind of becomes deterministic in a sense that it randomly pickes value from a group of the same values. So, Yes- it helps in solving problem of duplicates in cases like yours

Answer (score 2):

I think this is pretty clear in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators):

> **ANY_VALUE**
>
> ```
> ANY_VALUE(expression)  [OVER (...)]
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Returns any value from the input or NULL if there are zero input rows. The value returned is **non-deterministic**, which means you might receive a different result each time you use this function.

If you are depending on a particular value being returned, it is at your risk of it not working at some point.

I would instead recommend using window functions:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by . . . order by . . . ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This guarantees that all values are from the *same* row and you can control which row they come from -- assuming you have something to uniquely identify each row.