# What does ANY_VALUE() do in a GROUP BY context?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

An example of this usage is the solution posted here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726292/3565255).
The code looks like this (BigQuery, StandardSQL):

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(e).*, MAX(SentDateTime) SentDateTime
FROM `project.dataset.table2` e
JOIN `project.dataset.table1` s
ON e.EmailName = s.EmailName
AND EventDateTime > SentDateTime 
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', e)
```

From ANY_VALUE() documentation, I think I understand what the function does (return any value from the given set). I don't understand what it does in this context though.

When I leave out the GROUP BY line, it will return some row from the table. That's straightforward.
When the GROUP BY is added, it returns ALL rows from the table and that doesn't make sense to me. Can someone explain?

I interpret it as a way of grouping by all the columns without listing them explicitly somehow, but when I read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729262/bigquery-any-value-non-deterministic) post, it's a bit worrying to read "If you are depending on a particular value being returned, it is at your risk of it not working at some point."

Comment: let's say you are grouping by the hash of a values (in this case - `FORMAT('%t', e)` where e is the whole row of the table)  - so now , when you need to retrieve such a row itself  - you are using `ANY_VALUE(e)` - obviously all values in each group are the same  - so any value will always return same value from the group. and finally - you use `.*` to get all fields from that row. Thank simple! Hope now it is clear for you!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant this comment is an answer you should post as one.

Comment: posted as an answer per OP's ask.

Answer (score 5):

let's say you are grouping by the hash of a values (in this case - `FORMAT('%t', e`) where e is the whole row of the table) - so now , when you need to retrieve such a row itself - you are using `ANY_VALUE(e)` - obviously all values in each group are the same - so any value will always return same value from the group. and finally - you use `.*` to get all fields from that row. That simple! Hope now it is clear for you!

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify what is meant by "obviously all values in each group are the same"?

Comment: because you are grouping by hash of the rows  - all rows in the group are duplicate/same!!